# Django Tastypie with Apache LXML and DefusedXML: Error: "Usage of the xml aspects requires lxml and defusedxml"

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, tastypie

I have a Django app with a RESTFull service provided by Tastypie. I used easy_install to install lxml and defusedxml so I could use xml instead of json.  If I run manage.py runserver, it all works, but if I run it through apache and mod_wsgi on the same machine, I get an Improperly Configured error from Django saying

```
Usage of the xml aspects requires lxml and defusedxml
```

I am guessing it must be a path issue, but I can't seem to find anything to point me in the right direction.  Any ideas?

Comment: did you set the WSGIScriptAlias like explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/ in your apache config ?

Comment: Yes.  I should have put in there that the entire site works perfectly fine through apache, I just can't access the Tastypie api using xml.  ie /api/v1/people/?format=json works but /api/v1/people/?format=xml throws the lxml/defusedxml error.  It does not give me the error and returns the xml I am expecting if I use manage.py runserver, however.

Comment: I just dont use Django Tastypie but just found that in the doc you should have define the serializer in your ModelResource did do you it like explain here ? http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html#serialization

Comment: Yes, that is setup correctly.  Seems to be a python path issue, but unsure of how to resolve it...

Answer (score 5):

OK, so I found the answer to my not so well worded question.  When I ran easy_install, it never told me that lmxl had actually failed to install since I was missing a compiler.  I have no idea why it worked from the Django development server and not through Apache, but I found and installed a binary distribution of lxml and it all started working the way it should.